# How to implement responsibility chain with different types between processing classes

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection

The header of this question looks very strange, but i don't know how to name it clearly.

Here is the problem: i have a server, which can accept text messages and have 3 classes: `Pipeline`, `IParser` and `ISolver`. Pipeline combines parser and solver so that user can make different configuration of parsers and solvers, for example, he can use one parser for 3 or more solvers. All this stuff is loaded using reflection (concrete classes are loaded for parsers and solvers). This is very similar to chain of responsibility, but it has a following difference: parser parses text file to some class, let's call it `SolverData`. But the trouble is that different solvers apply different data. So how can i check the correctness of parsers output type and solver input type when loading this app?

Here are my code samples when i didn't use DI and had only one type of data for solvers:

```
 public class Pipeline
{
    private ISolver _itsSolver;

    private IParser _itsParser;

    public Initialize()
    {
        //init code
    }

    public string Execute(string userInput)
    {
        return _itsSolver.Execute(_itsParser.Parse(userInput));
    }
}

public interface ISolver
{
    string Execute(SolverData data);
}

public interface IParser
{
    SolverData Parse(string input);
}
```

Comment: An example code would be helpful

Comment: Agree with Miller - please show *code* which you have problem with. If  it's a generic question, not related to particular code, then it's better to ask it on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, added code to my post. So my problem is with SolverData class, some of my solvers need AnotherSolverData claa objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need different Parser interface for different SolverData...
might be something like:

```
public class SolverDataA {}
public class SolverDataB {}

public interface IParserA {
    SolverDataA Parse(string input);
}
public interface IParserB {
    SolverDataA Parse(string input);
}
public interface ISolver {
    string Execute(string input);
}
public class SolverA: ISolver {
   private readonly IParserA parser;
   public SolverA(IParserA parser){
      Requires.IsNotNull(parser, "parser");
      this.parser = parser;
   }
   public string Execute(string input) {
      SolverDataA da = parser.Parse(input);
      // solve
      return s;
   }
}
public class SolverB: ISolver {
   private readonly IParserB parser;
   public SolverB(IParserB parser){
      Requires.IsNotNull(parser, "parser");
      this.parser = parser;
   }
   public string Execute(string input) {
      SolverDataB db = parser.Parse(input);
      // solve
      return s;
   }
}
```

?

Comment: Hm, sounds good, i'll try this on. Thank you very much! I'll mark this as solution.